# Use variables in wordpress pages and update them regularly

Tags: wordpress, variables, shortcode

I am creating a Wordpress website to publish events (Wordpress is a mandatory). I have 5 pages to create. Each page stands for a music event. On each page there are 10 dates. The dates have to be updated each month.

I am looking for a way to create variables on my 5 pages. Each variable would be a music event date.

So I will have 50 variables:

- Event1_date1 : february 16th, 202O
- Event1_date2 :  february 17th, 202O
- Event1_date3 : february 18th, 202O
- ...
- Event5_date10 : june 3rd, 202O

**What is the right way to manage it on Wordpress?**

Thanks for your help

Comment: There a several ways to do this, but I would research custom meta fields and possibly Advanced Custom Fields plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to create custom fields but the easy way is

1) Use plugin [Advanced-Custom-Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)

- Create 5 pages and and you can assign custom input fields in all pages using this plugin
- There are some limitation you can not design your custom fields

2) Use function and add custom fields in admin page like this

- For that you can use **add_meta_box** function to your function.php file

  `add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_custom_codes_init_func' );
   function my_custom_codes_init_func() {
     add_meta_box('my_page', 'Pages', 'my_cutom_page', 'page','normal', 'low');
   }`

  Add Your own code which displayed on the page

  `function my_cutom_page(){
  global $post;
  global $wpdb;
  $post_id = $post->ID;
      ?>
      <h1>My image</h1>
      Name :<input>
      Date : <input type="date">
      <?php
  }`

  It Will display like this 
  [image]

  - For updating fields, you can use get_post_meta and update_post_meta
  - You can add your own css and own design structure
  - you can get post_id and execute the query using $wpdb in this function

Comment: Thanks for your help Vanapariya, really appreciate!